# How to get an email alert on schema update?

Tags: sql-server

Is there a simple way to get an email alert when table, view or stored procedure is updated (or ideally any database object)? Does SQL Server have a built in function for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built in capability for this but you may try a combination of [DDL triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190989%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and sp_send_dbmail to send email notification.

To do this you’ll need to create DDL triggers for all objects you want to monitor and include sp_send_dbmail stored procedure inside all those triggers.

To setup database mail you’ll need to configure it through SSMS first. [Here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/) is an article that describes this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with database level trigger and sp_send_dbmail procedure.